# "Updating the state with a prop" or idk

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-functional-component

Currently i'm working in a ReactJS course but it's a little bit deprecated so, i'm trying it with the goal to practice ReactJS in a current version.

The guy made something like:

[Setting a selectedItem prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3hza.png)

and then:
[updating the state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeSLV.png)

I'm trying to achieve this with "setState" somenthing but i receive an error saying that "selected genre" is not defined.

Here's my code:

```
  const handleGenreSelect = (genre) => {
    setAllGenres((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      selectedGenre: genre,
    }));
  };
```

With that I expect to update the state and set a listGroup item active when the user makes click over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a function component, which is great for practicing writing modern React code, but I think you might be getting mixed up between the format of the older class components used in course and the newer functional style.

Without seeing more of your code I can't be certain, but it looks like what you want to do something like this:

```
const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
const [selectedGenre, setSelectedGenre] = useState(null);

const handleGenreSelect = (genre) => {
    setSelectedGenre(genre);
}
```

Whereas in class components you would call `this.setState()` and pass it an object with multiple updated states at once, in a function component each state is updated separately.

The function you're calling, `setAllGenres()`, looks like it should be used to set your complete list of genres that the user can select from. In the example I shared above, I've tried to make it clear that you have two separate states - one for all of the genres, and one for the currently selected genre.

Comment: Your answer was great. I feel i am learning this in a good way because thinking in how to implement the topic for this question, I thought in some possibles ways to achieve it, and  separate states were part of that possibilities. Thank you for your time and your great explanation. 